# Is the blink drive essentially 'folding space' like in Dune?

Tags: dune, dark-matter

Although there are physical differences between the 'blink drive' used in the Dark Matter TV series and 'folding space' in Dune, are the concepts not basically the same?

Answer (score 5):

Not especially, beyond that both are fictional methods of faster-than-light travel.

The *Dune* series does not focus on the exact mechanics of space travel -- it is not a work of hard science fiction, after all -- but the semi-canonical *Dune Encyclopedia* gives some tantalizing details. (Note that some of these details conflict with the Brian Herbert sequels, making this answer somewhat specific to the *Dune Encyclopedia* canon.)

To summarize:

The Spacing Guild implemented space travel using a form of the Holtzman suspensor-nullification effect -- part of the same set of fictional forces that were used to implement defensive shields and suspensors. Activation of the suspensor-nullification effect causes a large sphere ("no more than a kilometer across") to enter "the Void", a sketchily described extradimensional space.

Space travel took place on large spherical ships (presumably sized to fit within the range of the suspensor-nullification effect) called *heighliners*, under the control of the Spacing Guild. The heighliner is controlled by a group of Guild Navigators. They use the prescience provided by large doses of melange spice to predict and correct for disturbances in the heighliner's course.

I can't find much detailed information on the *Dark Matter* "blink drive" online, but from what I gather, it's unlike space travel in Dune in several crucial ways:

- The "blink drive" is technological in nature. Space travel in *Dune* requires a biological element (the Guild navigator) to safely complete travel throughout most of the series. (The *Dune Encyclopedia* mentions that a computerized navigation system was eventually developed, but only in 14132, after the time period of the series.)
- The "blink drive" is instantaneous. Space travel in *Dune* is not instantaneous -- it is faster-than-light, but still takes time.
- > The "blink drive" can lead to time travel. No such effect is attested anywhere in the *Dune* series.

Comment: Looks like there is something missing at the end of the first bullet point :-)

Comment: The blink drive may not have been intended as a time travel device originally. It would seem that it was intended as a means to travel instantaneously to other regions of the galaxy and to explore the folding or warping of time and space (time-space continuum).

Comment: Are the Guild ships described as spherical in the encyclopaedia? I don’t remember them being described in that much detail in the book (didn’t really read many of the sequel/prequels). I recall them being cylindrical in one of the screen versions.

Comment: the space drives in Dune do not require a biological element. Navigation however is the other side of things. The Butlarian Jihad outlawed thinking machines. A thinking machine could manage the navigation.

Comment: @Darren _Dune Encyclopedia_, under HEIGHLINER: "The neutrino circuitry, mandated by field mechanics, relied much more on sheer power than on the elegant geometries characteristic of modern craft. For this reason a heighliner was a simple, featureless globe."

Comment: @Naib The _Dune Encyclopedia_ states that computerized navigation was not developed until 14132 -- after the death of Leto II.

Comment: @duskwuff that doesn't dispute what I said ... the actual drive does NOT require a biological element. The navigation does

Comment: @duskwuff thanks. For the record, I wasn’t disputing what you said, was merely curious. I wonder if there is a canonical source for the claim the ships are spherical.